# Interface Schneider EM6433H meter with ESP32 using ModbusMaster library

Tags: esp32, modbus, serial-communication, rs485

I have been trying to interface Schneider EM6433H meter with ESP32 in Arduino IDE using ModbusMaster library.

I'm trying to read current & power consumption of a phase. But I'm getting all the readings as 0. Even if i directly tried printing the output of the registers, still output is 0.
I'm reading the data from holding registers.

I can see the value of current & watt on the display of the meter, also it works fine in Modscan software.

The setting of the meter are as follows:

Parity : Even
Baud rate: 19200
Stop bit: 1
Register: Holding register
Meter setup: Single phase with neutral

Please see due to number of character constraints I'm not able to post the entire library here. so attaching the link for the same along with the changes I have done.

I have attached the header files in the code which I'm using currently( I have modified them as per my needs).

The getBufferRespose I changed back to 8bit because the address itself is 8bit format.

As of now I'm using the addresses given in the excel sheet shared by Schneider. I also try converting the address into HEX, but same result

The circuit works fine, I have tested it with other RS-485 meter.

I'm not getting the readings of the current or power, getting only 0, as an output of any register.

https://github.com/4-20ma/ModbusMaster this is the library I'm using, with the following changes

1. line 191 (ModbusMaster.h) uint16_t getResponseBuffer(uint16_t);
2. line 223 (ModbusMaster.h) static const uint16_t ku8MaxBufferSize                = 4086;   ///< size of response/transmit buffers
3. line 228 ( ModbusMaster.cpp ) uint16_t ModbusMaster::getResponseBuffer(uint16_t u8Index)

Pasting the output here

15974

21103

ovf

15974

21103

65472

0

65472

0

......

15975

12294

0.00

15975

12294

65472

0

65472

0

Attaching code for your reference.

```
#include <ModbusMaster.h>

/*!
  We're using a MAX485-compatible RS485 Transceiver.
  Rx/Tx is hooked up to the hardware serial port at 'Serial'.
  The Data Enable and Receiver Enable pins are hooked up as follows:
*/
#define MAX485_DE      2
#define MAX485_RE_NEG  4

// instantiate ModbusMaster object
ModbusMaster node;

void preTransmission()
{
  digitalWrite(MAX485_RE_NEG, 1);
  digitalWrite(MAX485_DE, 1);
}

void postTransmission()
{
  digitalWrite(MAX485_RE_NEG, 0);
  digitalWrite(MAX485_DE, 0);
}

float V1,V2,V3;

void setup()
{
  pinMode(MAX485_RE_NEG, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(MAX485_DE, OUTPUT);
  // Init in receive mode
  digitalWrite(MAX485_RE_NEG, 0);
  digitalWrite(MAX485_DE, 0);

  // Modbus communication runs at 115200 baud
  Serial2.begin(9600, SERIAL_8E1);     //Even parity & 1 stop bit baud rate 19200
  Serial.begin (115200);
  // Modbus slave ID 1
  node.begin(1, Serial2);
  // Callbacks allow us to configure the RS485 transceiver correctly
  node.preTransmission(preTransmission);
  node.postTransmission(postTransmission);
}

bool state = true;

void loop()
{
  uint8_t result1,result2,result3;
  uint16_t data1[6],data2[6],data3[6], data4[6];

  // Read 16 registers starting at 0x3100)
/*
    result1 = node.readHoldingRegisters(0xA8C,2);
    delay(100);
    if (result1 == node.ku8MBSuccess){
      Serial.println(node.getResponseBuffer(0xA8C));
      Serial.println(node.getResponseBuffer(0xA8D));
    }*/
    result1 = node.readHoldingRegisters(0x0BB7,10);
    if (result1 == node.ku8MBSuccess){

      data1[0] = node.getResponseBuffer(0x0);
      data1[1] = node.getResponseBuffer(0x1);

      Serial.println( data1[0]);
      Serial.println( data1[1]);
      float I2 = *((float *)data1);
      Serial.println( I2 );

      Serial.println( node.getResponseBuffer(0x0) );
      Serial.println( node.getResponseBuffer(0x1) );
      Serial.println( node.getResponseBuffer(0x2) );
      Serial.println( node.getResponseBuffer(0x3) );
      Serial.println( node.getResponseBuffer(0x4) );
      Serial.println( node.getResponseBuffer(0x5) );
    }
  Serial.println( "......" );
  delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: I would have expected your calls to `getResponseBuffer` to return `0xFFFF`? `getResponseBuffer` is passed "Index index of response buffer array" not the register number (so pass 0 to retrieve the first value read as per [the example](https://github.com/4-20ma/ModbusMaster/blob/master/examples/Basic/Basic.pde#L58)).

Comment: @Brits I'm getting 0xFFFF, now after trying this example

Comment: "Parity : Even, Baud rate: 19200, Stop bit: 1", then why `Serial2.begin(9600, SERIAL_8E1);`?

Comment: @Archana so your original code if now returning `0xFFFF`? Please update the question with your current code and also show us it's full output (best to simplify the example so it only gets one register).

Comment: Doesn't "Parity : Even, Baud rate: 19200, Stop bit: 1", then why Serial2.begin(9600, SERIAL_8E1); means the same thing?
I thought so, referred this link https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/begin/

Comment: @Brits, the code posted above is the one I'm using & I'm getting all 0 as output. Attaching the output for reference.
14:11:08.490 -> 0
14:11:08.490 -> 0
14:11:08.490 -> 0.00
14:11:08.490 -> 0.00
14:11:08.490 -> 0.00

Comment: Unless I'm missing something; `uint16_t ModbusMaster::getResponseBuffer(uint8_t u8Index)` accepts a byte (`uint8_t`), you are passing in `0x0BB8` (i.e. two bytes) so the result will not be as you expect (I also believe a request for 120 registers will exceed the default internal buffer).

Comment: @Brits To overcome this issue I have changed the uint16_t ModbusMaster::getResponseBuffer(uint8_t u8Index) to uint16_t ModbusMaster::getResponseBuffer(uint16_t u8Index) and made the changes at the necessary places in the library

Comment: static const uint16_t ku8MaxBufferSize                = 4086;   ///< size of response/transmit buffers
uint16_t getResponseBuffer(uint16_t);

uint16_t ModbusMaster::getResponseBuffer(uint16_t u8Index)
{ 
  
  if (u8Index < ku8MaxBufferSize)
  {
    return _u16ResponseBuffer[u8Index];
  }
  else
  {
    return 0xFFFF;
  }
}

Comment: @Archana changing the library is not really the answer (in my opinion) the existing library should be capable of meeting your needs. Unfortunately we now cannot really help further without access to your modified library (please don't past code into comments; edit the question).

Comment: When the library runs the query it puts the results into the buffer from position 0 (not the register #). So you are reading unaltered parts of the buffer; as per previous comment see the example.

Comment: @Brits I so you mean that for readHoldingRegister I need to put the reference address as 0 ? Instead of 3000 or 0x0BB8 ?

If I do so then the problem is I have to read the register 3000 and the no of words to be read is limited to 120, for the readHoldingregister function

Comment: No, just get the registers as is. When retrieving them from the buffer reg 0x0bb8 will be in position 0.

Comment: @Brits, can you please elaborate with an example?

Comment: result1 = node.readHoldingRegisters(0x0000,120); 
If I write this way then I'll able to read only 120 registers, starting from 0x0000, but I want to read 0x0bb8,  how to make it possible?

Comment: Still I tried but I'm getting 0 as the output of the getBufferResponse(0x0bb8); function

Comment: Use the code you pasted only changing to `getBufferResponse(0x0)` (this will give you regiser `0x0bb8`, assuming read is `node.readHoldingRegisters(0x0BB8,1);`)

Comment: result1 = node.readHoldingRegisters(0x0BB8,10);
    if (result1 == node.ku8MBSuccess){

      data1[0] = node.getResponseBuffer(0x0);
      data1[1] = node.getResponseBuffer(0x0);

      Serial.println( data1[0], HEX );
      Serial.println( data1[1], HEX );
      float I2 = *((float *)data1);
      Serial.println( I2 );

@ Brits I tried what you had mentioned before, I'm getting a following response can you please tell me how to proceed further?
> 454B
12:01:55.815 -> 454B
12:01:55.815 -> 3252.33
12:01:55.815 -> 0.00
12:01:55.815 -> 0.00
12:01:55.815 -> ......

Comment: I think it's time for a new question (its really hard to read code in the comments). Anyway you are getting data which is a start; I would try requesting from 0xBB7 (there are different ways of numbering the registers so try +/-1) and output all of the raw data. Then use something like [this tool](https://www.scadacore.com/tools/programming-calculators/online-hex-converter/); chuck the value of TWO registers (from the spec these are 32 bit floats so 2 x 16 bit registers) in and check the results to see if the value is what you expect (the spec does not dictate how to encode floats).

Comment: @Brits, I tried But I'm getting some issues. I'm editing the questions so that I can put it clearly.

Comment: Please print out the raw figures (from register 0xBB7 output about 5 registers). Please also provide the values you are expecting to see `3e64 a29d` would be `0.22327657`). You need to do this one step at a time; ensure you are reading the correct registers then look at the conversion to float (I suspect endianness might be an issue there).

Comment: @Brits I tried your suggestion but didn't work, I have pasted the output by modifying the questions & also pasted the modified code

Comment: "but didn't work" - how do you know? (you still seem to be assuming that the way you are converting to floating point is correct, but that has not been established). `FFC00000` (65472 & 0) is repeated twice, and can be decoded to `NaN` (so an invalid reading) which may the expected result, depending upon what you have connected (but as you have not provided expected values I can't know). Sorry - I'm out (way too many comments here.

Comment: @Brits, I,m trying to measure current & power consumption, i can verify the readings on the display of the meter but i don't have a way to verify the raw readings. Also idk how to convert the raw readings into floats apart from the method mentioned above

Comment: Then put that info in the question (e.g. "the meter screen says x, so I'm expecting to read a similar figure via modbus"). You sanity check your modbus readings against the values on the screen...